# Create nested class for Firebase data save and read

Tags: class, firebase, model, ionic3

I have the following structure in Firebase for my user's.

```
Root
|
----user
      |
      ----public
          |
          -name_first:''
          -name_last: ''
          |
      ----private
          |
          -birthday: ''
          -gender:''
```

I am working with Ionic3 and Angular2. So how do I structure my model class for data save and read?
I have a model TS called `user` which has a `user` class. Do I create 2 subclasses inside that for `public` and `private` or there is any better approach?

Comment: This is unclear: why do you have public and private child nodes within the user node? What's preventing your class from saving and reading?

Comment: In times I just want to fetch the public data from the user and not the entire object. Regarding the class, I want to know how should I structure it.

Comment: It's still unclear. What can't you read the */user/uid/private* node for private data and the */user/uid/public* node for public data?

Comment: There is no problem in reading or writing data. I just want to know what is the best way to Create the model class.